# DAX-How to achieve a year-to-date per category?

Tags: dax

My problem is the following:

I have a table like this one below:

```
Date           Category    Value      Movment Value
2019-01-01     105         1000       1000
2019-02-05     110         1200       200
2019-03-25     100         800        -400
2019-03-28     100         700        -100
2019-04-15     95          1300       600
```

To get the value at date, I can calculate a year-to-date on the Movment Value column (because the Value column **is not additive** with respect to Date column).

Things get worse when I filter on Category column. The year-to-date gives me these values per category which is correct:

```
Category: 95     100     105     110
YTD     : 600    -500    1000    200
```

But the result I am looking for is:

```
Category: 95     100     105     110
YTD     : 1300    700    1000    1200
```

What I tried is this formula:
IF(NOT(ISFILTERED([Category])); [Movment Value YTD]; [Movment Value Reset Per Category YTD]),

where [Movment Value Reset Per Category] is the year-to-date of reset movment, i.e.

```
Date        Category    Value   Movment Value   Movment Value Per Category
2019-01-01  105         1000    1000            1000
2019-02-05  110         1200    200             1200
2019-03-25  100         800     -400            800
2019-03-28  100         700     -100            -100
2019-04-15  95          1300    600             1300
```

It works, but if we use multiple dimensions to filter on, it could become very complicated to manage.

Do you have an idea, how I can achieve this "special" YTD per category without having to manage all cases ?

Thank you for your inputs.

Marco

Comment: Please show us the DAX you use for the [Movement Value Reset Per Category]. You shouldn't have to create one measure for each dimension: https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/

Comment: It looks like you only need the value of each category for the **latest date**. Is that correct? If it is do you not need the other values at all?